# How do I add a model method to the user session?

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js, models

I have an `User` model, and I'm using *Passport.js*, in *Sails.js*. With this setup, `req.user` returns current user session details, as in `req.user.username` returns "Jimmy", for Jimmy's session.

I find this very handy for layout purposes, and I'd also like to add a method that finds user settings, accesible via `req.user`.

My method (inside of the `User` model), as of now, looks like this:

```
  getSetting: function(code) {

        UserSettings.find({ where: { user: req.user.id, code: code } }).exec(function(err, setting) {
            return setting.value;
        });

  }
```

How could I make this method accessible through `req.user`, so that when I do `req.user.getSetting('TEST_CODE');` I get the desired setting value for THAT user?

Or otherwise, how could I access the user's settings easily? I have an `UserSettings` model that is associated with the `User` model.

**EDIT:**

The User model I have:

```
var User = {

  schema: true,

  attributes: {
    username  : { type: 'string', unique: true },
    email     : { type: 'email',  unique: true },
    passports : { collection: 'Passport', via: 'user' },
    settings  : { collection: 'UserSettings', via: 'user' }
  },

  getSetting: function(code) {

        UserSettings.find({ where: { user: req.user.id, code: code } }).exec(function(err, setting) {
            return setting.value;
        });

  }

};

module.exports = User;
```

Thanks.

Comment: The sails.js gitter room is also a good place to chat and get support: https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have looked the [Sail.js documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Models.html) and it turns out they use another method to create models, so I'm rewriting my answer.

What you want is an [attribute method](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Models.html?q=attribute-methods-(ie-record%2Finstance-methods)), so you need to define your function inside the `attributes` key:

```
var User = {

  schema: true,

  attributes: {
    username  : { type: 'string', unique: true },
    email     : { type: 'email',  unique: true },
    passports : { collection: 'Passport', via: 'user' },
    settings  : { collection: 'UserSettings', via: 'user' },

    getSetting: function(code, cb) {

          UserSettings.find({ where: { user: this.id, code: code } }).exec(function(err, setting) {
              cb(setting.value);
          });

    }
  }

};

module.exports = User;
```

But the matter of not being able to return the value directly still stands, you need to pass it as a parameter to a callback function.

Comment: Hmmm, well, I truly don't know how the User model data ended up `req.user`. I mean, it's user data going around in req, which stands for request, right? I don't know if every model can be accesed by `req.model`. 
Sails.js way of handling models is a bit different than that, and I think that by adding a property that has a function to the model (which I have already done), I'm doing something equivalent to what you've suggested. However, I can't access the method by req (request) still. I mean, I can access it through User.getSetting(), but I'd like to use it in layouts.

Comment: You are right, I have rewritten my answer. I didn't pay attention you were using Sails.js

Comment: Oh, it was a matter of adding it to the attributes! I hadn't thought of that haha, thanks for looking into it. This sets me on the right path, I think. Thanks.